# Laravel unique department for each company

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, uniqueidentifier

I have a table named departments where 2 columns 1. name 2. company, I want to apply validation on name for single company.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $company = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $this->validate($request, [
        'company'=>'unique:departments,company',
    ]);

    $department = Department::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'company' => $request->company,
    ]);
  }
```

expected result of departments is

```
name      company
======================
Accounts    1
Purchase    1
Accounts    2
Sales       2
Accounts    2  //wrong i want validation here
Purchase    1  //wrong i want validation here
```

Comment: have you set the unique constraint on the field name in your table? @MuhammadKazim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the format of unique validation `unique:table,column,except,idColumn` details https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique.
And with adding additional where condition it will be like this `unique:table,column,except,idColumn,anotherColumn,anotherColumnValue`

Add validation on department name

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //If getting company from request 
    $company = $request->company;

    //if getting company from auth user
    $company = Auth::user()->company_id;

    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:departments,name,NULL,id,company,'. $company
    ]);

    $department = Department::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'company' => $company,
    ]);
}
```

**Note:** Better if you change the `company` column name to `company_id` in department because you are storing company id in it.

Comment: Thank u so much sir.

Answer (score 1):

So, the relationship is many to many? Each company have same group of departments.
I suggest creating a new relationship table. would be `company_department`, contains at least 2 columns: `department_id` and `company_id` - by this, you will easily manage data, also easily query to access database.
Hope it will be usefull.